# how to add Customer Name

Tags: global-payments-api

```
$hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData();
$hostedPaymentData->customerEmail = $this->customer_email;
$hostedPaymentData->customerPhoneMobile = $this->customer_mobile_phone;
$hostedPaymentData->addressesMatch = false;
```

How to add customer name in hosted payment data

Answer (score 0):

The following all work, the comments are the POST variables they populate when requesting the HPP.

```
// HPP_NAME
$hostedPaymentData->customerName = 'asdf hjkl';

// HPP_CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME
$hostedPaymentData->customerFirstName = 'asdf';

// HPP_CUSTOMER_LASTNAME
$hostedPaymentData->customerLastName = 'hjkl';
```